# Capturing byte from string [play framework]

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean, bitarray

Actually I am trying to capture job working days of a particular job post. The project is in Play Framework.

I have created a model something like this:

```
@Column(name = "JobPostWorkingDays", columnDefinition = "binary(7) null")

private BitArray jobPostWorkingDays;
```

I am getting the input as a string like this:

```
workingDays = '1111100'; (mon,tue,wed,thurs,fri.sat,sun)
```

I am unable to understand how to manipulate the data and save in MySql Database. Please help!